# How to combine all the columns in into one and count them respectively in google sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, aggregate

[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sfMLD.png)

Hi everyone,

I have 3 columns of data for the age of people in a city and also 3 columns of the count for the ages. I want to combine all the 6 columns into 2 columns which means there will be only one column of age data and one column for number of count. I try to use query function in googlesheet but not sure how to use it. Please give me some advice on this if there is other method that can achieve the same result. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
=query({G8:H; J9:K; M9:N}, "Select Col1, sum(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 label sum(Col2) 'Count of people'", 1)
```

and see if that works?

and see if that works?

[image]